# How to run again the clock, since the time returned by the API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I  got response from api, object which has a property --> seconds:70.
How to run the clock from those 70 seconds. Which property should I changed in `this.setState ({}) timerTime, timerStart`, to set a new time (70 seconds) and run the clock?. I can use the moment library to set a new time.

All code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rbv2pd

**Code snippet:**

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      timerTime: 70  //I  get response from api {seconds:70}
    })
  }

  startTimer = () => {
    this.setState({
      timerOn: true,
      timerTime: this.state.timerTime,
      timerStart: Date.now() - this.state.timerTime
    });
    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({
        timerTime: Date.now() - this.state.timerStart
      });
    }, 10);
  };
```

Comment: In your link everything is working fine. What is your requirement exactly?

Comment: @MonikaMangal I want to initiate the fetch of data from Api(70 seconds). Set in omponentDidMount(70 sec). That the clock appears 70 seconds (1m 10s) -> click start -> run clock from 70 sec

Comment: @MonikaMangal do you know what I mean?

Comment: Oh, you mean you want to start from 70 seconds instead of 0

Comment: @MonikaMangal Yes. If response from api --seconds 70. I want to start from 70, if 30 seconds I want to start from 30 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the value you get from the api to milliseconds and then assign it to timerTime -

```
componentDidMount() {
   const valueInMilliSec = valueFromApi * 1000;
    this.setState({
      timerTime: valueInMilliSec  //I  get response from api {seconds:70}
    })
  }
```

In your case -

```
this.setState({
      timerTime: 70000                       
    })
```

Comment: @Umbro and you need to change some logic for the showing of buttons as well if you want to show 'start' button at 70 seconds instead of 'resume' and 'reset'